# Can any one access my sqlite3 database from an app in iPhone when phone is lost

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, osx-snow-leopard

I have created an application in which I have fetched personal information from the website and stored in my sqlite3 local database.The authenticate user only see their information after successful logIN. Then I am displaying it as required. I do not want these information to be hacked by anyone when the phone is lost.

I have implemented the feature that when the app comes to foreground from the background it will ask for the pin which is hardcoded in the app.

My questions:

1. Can any one access my sqlite3 local database when the phone is lost ?
2. Is there any way to encrypt the database and decrypt it when required ?
3. How I will be sure that the database is not vulnerable .

Thanking you

Comment: Authentication information sounds like it should go into the keychain.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *dbPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myDatadase.sqlite"];
if (sqlite3_open_v2([dbPath UTF8String], &database, SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE|SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE|SQLITE_OPEN_FILEPROTECTION_COMPLETEUNTILFIRSTUSERAUTHENTICATION, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){
    NSLog(@"db opened securely");
}else{
    NSLog(@"db not opened");
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for docs on `SQLITE_OPEN_FILEPROTECTION_COMPLETEUNTILFIRSTUSERAUTHENTICATION` but haven't found any.

Answer (score 0):

1. Anyone can access your file if they can get the phone (which is not so hard e.g. using iPhone Explorer)
2. I googled and found http://sqlcipher.net/. Take a look.
3. If you are encrypting your database using user-supplied password, so I think it is secured enough in your part. The vulnerable might exist in encryption part or so, but we can never be sure.

Comment: it is not a file. It is a database which is inside an app.  Can any one access the database using iPhone Explorer ?

Comment: It IS a file. "A complete database is stored in a single cross-platform disk file." - http://www.sqlite.org/features.html. And yes, no matter it is inside or outside application bundle, iPhone Explorer can access it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this your problem to solve? It could be best to educate the user to use the [Find My iPhone](http://www.apple.com/au/iphone/built-in-apps/find-my-iphone.html) app to remotely wipe their lost iPhone. Savvy users will do this automatically to protect their contacts, and saved passwords to PayPay, eBay etc.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, yes, your information may well be accessible.

If your database contains confidential information it should be, at a minimum, stored using the iOS Secure File Storage mechanisms (assuming the OS supports it... IIRC it's iOS 4+).

For sqlite, to your sqlite3_open_v2() call pass one of the rather unwieldy

SQLITE_OPEN_FILEPROTECTION_COMPLETE...

options to enable secure file storage.  These constants are declared with the rest of them in sqlite3.h.

Comment: I am not writing to any file or not using any file. What information I will fetch form the website that is stored in the database.                 Examples are welcome .

Comment: Are you saying that you are using a pure in-memory database (http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html)? If not, then there *is* a file.